# How to assign a function when doing proxy context matching in the webpack-dev-server's proxy config?

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

For example of my `webpack.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    devServer: {
        proxy: {
            '/api': {
                target: 'http://localhost:3000',
                pathRewrite: {'/api': ''}
            }
        }
    },
    ....
}
```

Here, I used `/api` to match one url rule. But I looked into `http-proxy-middleware` which is the base of the `webpack-dev-server`'s `proxy`, it said that we can use a `filter function` to do the `custom match`:

```
var filter = function (pathname, req) {
    return (pathname.match('^/api') && req.method === 'GET');
};
var apiProxy = proxy(filter, {target: 'http://www.example.org'})
```

But in `webpack.config.js`, how could I use a `filter function` to do my `custom match`? Thanks.

Comment: hi im in the same situation need to ignore "sockjs-node" based requests dide you find any solution for using that filter function ?

Answer (score 5):

```
devServer: {
    proxy: [
        {
            target: 'http://api.example.com',
            context: function(pathname, req) {
                if (/^\/api/.test(pathname)) {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Reference: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverproxy

Comment: Thanks for this answer. The linked documentation doesn't explain this.